# Running multiple instances of Apache tomcat will not work in my pc

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I have two jdks and jres installed in my pc `java 1.5` and `java 1.8` for some work purpose. Now I have one instance of tomcat 5.5 which I took from another pc and pasted it in my pc `c:/servers folder`. It is running fine using java 1.5. So I set the `JAVA_HOME` and path to `java 1.5`. Now I downloaded tomcat 7 binary distribution zip file and extracted it in my `c:/servers` directory. I changed the connector port, shutdown port and AJP port to different values. set `CATALINA_BASE` to `c:/servers` directory. But when I'm running the startup.bat two windows are popping up for a sec and they are closing. The server is not starting. I found the error as `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError. Bad version number in class file`

[image]

Then I tried to install tomcat 8 using windows installer with again different port numbers in the same `c:/servers` directory which worked perfectly. It started and tomcat home screen also loaded. My work is survived with tomcat installer but I want to know why manual configuration failed.

OS = windows 10 64 bit

Please help me in making manual configuration of tomcat. If any other information is needed, I'll provide.

**EDIT 1**

I got this error `java.lang.InvocationTargetException` when I tried to install another instance of tomcat 5.5 manually in `c:/servers` directory

[image]

Comment: Looks like your Tomcat 7 is using the wrong `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider If that is the case then tomcat 8 shouldn't work either. But that is working right? anyways, I also thought that and I gave another environmental variable with JAVA8HOME and set it to jdk 1.8. That I used in the config files instead of JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception `UnsupportedClassVersionError` occurs when you try to execute *.class files with an older version of Java as they were compiled for.

In your case, you are trying to run Tomcat 7 with Java 1.5, but its minimum requirement for the JRE is version 1.6. The latest version of Tomcat that supports Java 1.5 is Tomcat 6. Check out this overview for more information:
[Apache Tomcat Versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

Comment: If that is the case then tomcat 8 shouldn't work either. But that is working right? anyways, I also thought that and I gave another environmental variable with JAVA8HOME and set it to jdk 1.8. That I used in the config files instead of JAVA_HOME. I still had no luck

Comment: Maybe you are logically correct. I checked trying to install tomcat 5.5 manually again. It didn't gave me `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. This time I got `java.lang.InvocationTargetException`. Any solution for this @vchris

Comment: `InvocationTargetException` occurs when an exception is thrown by a method that is invoked by reflection. It wraps the causing exception. From your screenshot in your question you can see that the InvocationTargetException wraps a `NullPointerException` from the method `org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.awake` - but this will not turn out to be very helpful I think. From the previous messages above you can see that there is also a problem with the configuration (loading `server.xml`). Try to find out the cause for that first, I assume the NullPointerException is a consequential error.

Comment: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html 

I used this link to configure the tomcat. Can you help in any way?

Comment: yup I Found out the solution. I unnecessarily set the CATALINA_BASE path to `c:\servers`. Once I deleted it and started tomcat 5.5, it worked perfectly. Better add this in your answer as it may help any other(May be there is any guy who makes silly mistakes).